# Word: Creating a visual graph that can be highlighted by the reader

Tags: microsoft-word

My supervisor has tasked me with creating a visual concentric graph for our international employees to fill in as a wellness exercise. The basic concept is that they answer 8 sections of questions, tally their answers for each series, and it gives them a "score" for each section. Then they need to be able to go to a graph and, ideally, highlight the field that corresponds with their score. The goal is to give a visible representation of how they're doing, showing what areas are strong and which are weak. The problem is, I have no idea how to do this! If they could print it out, they could shade it in with a marker, but it needs to be all digital. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Concentric Graph]